# Can you override content in the "static content" block when extending classes in geb?

Tags: geb, pageobjects

I have 2 classes one extends the other they are listed below:

```
class TabledPage extends Page {

    static content ={
        table {$(By.xpath("//tbody"))}
        headers {$(By.xpath("//thead"))}
    }

    Navigator gatAllRows(){
        return table.children()
    }

    Navigator getRow(int index){
        return table.children()[index]
    }

    Navigator getRow(String name){
        return table.children().find{it.text()==name}
    }

    Navigator getColumn(Navigator row, int column){
        return row.children()[column]
    }


}
```

and this class which extends the above class:

```
class somePage extends TabledPage{
    static content ={
        table(required: false){$(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'w-100 table-striped wi-table-hover')]//tbody"))} // I want this to overwrite the table def in TabledPage
    }
}
```

So in the app I am testing most of the pages only have 1 table, but in some cases there are 2 tables (one is hidden depending on screen size) so I want to be able to override the table definition in this case to point to a specific table, can I do this without also overriding the getRow methods or would those need to be overridden as well?

Just to give an example of how I am calling this alswell:

```
at SomePage
getRow(0)
```

this works but it uses the TabledPage definition of the table Navigator instead of the somePage definition and I am wondering if there is a way for me to make it use the other definition

Comment: I ended up re-defining the table definition in TabledModule to work with all the various pages, but I am still curious if what I am suggesting is possible

Comment: What makes you believe that _ it uses the TabledPage definition of the table Navigator instead of the somePage definition_? I belive that the content overriding works the way you expect. So I'm wondering if what you observed was not due to the definition from `TabledPage` being used but due to something completely different.

Comment: @erdi I will try to re-test this when I get a chance and let you know what I find

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you changed the content from the Spec instead of from the page? This is how I'm using dynamic selectors in a page:

```
static content=
{
    quantityField{$("$quantitySelector")
}

void setSelectors(tableIndex, row)
{
    quantitySelector="#offerDtos$tableIndex\\.segments$row\\.quantity"
}
```

In my spec, I just call setSelectors with the appropriate values.